# Passing elements of array to method that accepts ints (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, int, typecasting-operator

I'm trying to create an array of numbers, pass them to a static method that only accepts ints as parameters, and returns the maximum int to main to be printed(these are the homework specs). The max method works in its own, but I can't pass the array I input in main to the function, and get the max value back. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class findMax {
    public static int max(int val1, int val2, int val3) {
        int[] intArray = new int[3];
        val1 = intArray[0];
        val2 = intArray[1];
        val3 = intArray[2];
        int max = Math.max(Math.max(val1, val2), val3);
        System.out.println(max);
        return max;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] intArray = new int[3];
    System.out.println("Enter 3 integers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        intArray[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(intArray[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Input values: " + sb.toString());
    max(intArray[0], intArray[1], intArray[2]);
    System.out.println(max(intArray[0], intArray[1], intArray[2]));
    sc.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your `max` method overwrites its' parameters with zeros, so no it doesn't work on its' own.

```
public static int max(int val1, int val2, int val3) {
    int[] intArray = new int[3]; // {0, 0, 0}
    val1 = intArray[0]; // <-- val1 = 0
    val2 = intArray[1]; // <-- val2 = 0
    val3 = intArray[2]; // <-- val3 = 0
    int max = Math.max(Math.max(val1, val2), val3);
    System.out.println(max);
    return max;
}
```

should be something like

```
public static int max(int val1, int val2, int val3) {
    return Math.max(Math.max(val1, val2), val3);
}
```

Then your `main` method should work as expected (but you don't need to call `max` twice like that, just once when you print it).

```
// max(intArray[0], intArray[1], intArray[2]);
System.out.println(max(intArray[0], intArray[1], intArray[2]));
```

**and** you might prefer `Arrays.toString(intArray);` over your current `for` loop.

Alternatively, you might make `max` variadic (and assuming you are using Java 8+, use an `IntStream`). Like,

```
public static int max(int... values) {
    return IntStream.of(values).max().orElse(-1);
}
```

Which can be called like

```
System.out.println(max(intArray));
```

**or**

```
System.out.println(max(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Comment: I was obviously over-thinking the problem. Thanks so much for the help.